# Why readonly inputs don't fire focus event on tab key press on iPad?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ipad, input

I am facing this issue with iPad Pro.

I have a form where I have made all the fields `readonly` to prevent auto fill/auto complete.

I remvoe the `readonly` attribute when user clicks on the input field so that he can edit the field.

Below is my directive in Angular 8 which WORKS EVERYWHERE, BUT NOT IN IPAD.

How to make this work on iPad?

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[AutofillOff]'
})
export class AutofillOffDirective {

  @HostBinding('attr.readonly')
  readonly: boolean = true;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
    this.setEditable(this.el);
  }

  @HostListener('touchstart') onTouch() {
    this.setEditable(this.el);
  }

  @HostListener('focus') onFocus() {
    this.setEditable(this.el);
  }

  @HostListener('blur') onBlur() {
    this.setReadonly(this.el);
  }

  setEditable(inputField) {
    inputField.nativeElement.removeAttribute('readonly');
  }

  setReadonly(inputField) {
    inputField.nativeElement.readOnly = true;
  }



}
```

Comment: Can't you use autocomplete="off"?